# Android Studio - Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality

Tags: android, flutter

Considering that I had followed all this steps https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/linux in my Ubuntu 18.04LTS, why this following problem continues to appear:

```
$ flutter doctor -v
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.7.8+hotfix.2, on Linux, locale en_US.UTF-8)
    • Flutter version 1.7.8+hotfix.2 at /opt/flutter
    • Framework revision 2e540931f7 (2 weeks ago), 2019-07-02 09:31:07 -0700
    • Engine revision b1cb0d9e9b
    • Dart version 2.4.0

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
    • Android SDK at /home/rodrigo/Android/Sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling
      support)
    • Platform android-28, build-tools 28.0.3
    • ANDROID_HOME = /home/rodrigo/Android/Sdk
    • Java binary at: /usr/share/android-studio/jre/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build
      1.8.0_152-release-1343-b16-5323222)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Android Studio (version 3.4)
    • Android Studio at /usr/share/android-studio
    • Flutter plugin version 37.1.1
    • Dart plugin version 183.6270
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build
      1.8.0_152-release-1343-b16-5323222)

[!] Android Studio
    • Android Studio at /opt/android-studio
    ✗ Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    ✗ Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build
      1.8.0_152-release-1343-b16-5323222)

[✓] Connected device (1 available)
    • Android SDK built for x86 • emulator-5554 • android-x86 • Android 10 (API
      29) (emulator)

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

Different from another similar questions here in StackOverflow, before I've installed flutter plugin the "[✓] Android Studio (version 3.4)" was equal to "[!] Android Studio", with same error messages. After I've installed flutter plugin (and dart), only "[!] Android Studio" still displaying the error.

Does someone know why? I've made many searches in my files, I have only one Android Studio installed. Why displays two? What "[!] Android Studio" refer to? Does command "$ flutter doctor" have a problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This can be solved in simple steps:

Step 1: Open Android Studio

Step 2: Open Android Studio Preferences

Step 3: Go-to Plugins tab

Step 4: Click on MarketPlace tab

Step 5: Search for flutter in search box

You will see a list of plugins related to flutter. Click on the first one and check which version it is. Currently, the latest version is 37.1.1.

Step 6: Click on install. (It may ask you to install dart plugin also. Hit yes and android studio will install dart and flutter for you)

Ready to rock !

Comment: Thank you Abhishek, but your steps didn't solve. What I'm trying to understand here firstly is "what is that line written: [!] Android Studio". Because before I ran your steps, the "[!] Android Studio (version 3.4)" was with the exclamation mark with the same problem mentioned at "[!] Android Studio". After your steps, only "[✓] Android Studio (version 3.4)" changed to check mark. Then, what would be this "[!] Android Studio"!? A bug? Is this alert some missing configuration in flutter? 's odd.

Comment: Exclamation mark (!) Is simply a notifier which tells you that flutter might have some problem in this section. In your case, [!] Android Studio means flutter have some problem with Android Studio. [✓] Android studio means there's no problem with Android studio and you are ready to go! ;)

Comment: And ya, as per your question, I found that you have two install location of android studio in your system. One is "/usr/share/android-studio" and second is "/opt/android-studio". Please remove any one of them from your system. May be you have installed android studio for all users which resulted into this issue.

Comment: Great! It has been solved. You were right, in my case I used to store Android Studio at /usr/share/android-studio and a symbolic link to /opt/android-studio. I've unlinked the symbolic link and moved /usr/share/android-studio to /opt/android-studio. After that, $ flutter doctor displayed "success"! Another thing, at my work I had set $ flutter config --android-studio-dir=/opt/android-studio/ and the last slash generate an error too, the directory set need to be exactly, I solved with $flutter config --android-studio-dir=/opt/android-studio without last slash! Thank you again.

Answer (score 19):

This post is for those who have gotten the plug-ins installed but still receive the warning.

> Note: The Flutter team has created an issue for the inability of doctor to detect installed plug-ins. It's a know issue and they are looking to deprecate this detection feature of doctor:
>
> - https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/61246

---

My flutter and dart plug-ins are correctly installed but I still get the warning.

```
[!] Android Studio (version 4.0)
    ✗ Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    ✗ Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
```

**In my case ignoring the warning worked fine.**

I tried re-installing plug-ins several times but that **did not remove the warning** from `flutter doctor`.

However, everything **works fine**. I can successfully create and run apps created from

- the command line with `flutter create`
- from Android Studio with `File->New->New Flutter Project`

I'm on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and Android Studio 4.0.1 (installed through [JetBrains toolbox](https://www.jetbrains.com/toolbox-app/))

I installed flutter via the snap store:

```
sudo snap install flutter --classic
sudo snap install flutter-gallery
flutter channel dev
flutter upgrade
flutter config --enable-linux-desktop

# wanted to try web, apparently requires beta channel
flutter channel beta
flutter channel upgrade
flutter config --enable-web
```

**FYI, it took me a while to understand where the Flutter SDK was located.** It is here: `/home/(username)/snap/flutter/common/flutter`

**Plugins installed correctly, but still get warning:**
[image: Android Studio Plugins for Flutter and Dart installed]

Comment: this warning so fool, I wasted time looking for answers..thanks

Comment: Just switched to Ubunu from Windows and faced the same problem. Everything works fine but the error bothers me every time I run flutter doctor. Did you find any solutions for this?

Answer (score 3):

I recently encountered this problem, I first tried to update the flutter and dart plugin from the android studio market place, but that did not work

Finally, I run the following command and it worked like a charm

```
ln -s ~/Library/Application\ Support/Google/AndroidStudio4.1/plugins ~/Library/Application\ Support/AndroidStudio4.1
```

Note: I'm on Mac OS running android studio 4.1