# No Connected Devices Found in a Flutter App in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, dart, android-virtual-device

I read StackOverflow questions including the following ones:

- [flutter run: No connected devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49045393/flutter-run-no-connected-devices)
- [No connected devices found; please connect a device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60393155/no-connected-devices-found-please-connect-a-device)
- [Android studio - flutter: No Connected Devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62991298/android-studio-flutter-no-connected-devices)

**BUT**, I couldn't solve my issue....... :-(

---

My Flutter folder structure

- `D:\src\flutter`
- `D:\src\sdk`

My Project folder location : `D:\__GitHub`

---

Flutter SDK Setup Steps

- Add the following User environment variable

  - Variable Name : `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT`
  - Variable Value : `D:\src\sdk`
- Edit the "PATH" variable in the User enviroment variable

  - `D:\src\flutter\bin;`
  - `%ANDROID_SDK_ROOT%\tools;`
  - `%ANDROID_SDK_ROOT%\platform-tools;`
- Run `flutter config --android-sdk [sdk location]` in the terminal
- Run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` in the terminal

---

Launch an AVD in the emulator

- `D:\__GitHub\netninja_flutter_app` >    `flutter doctor --android-licenses`

  - All SDK package licenses accepted
- `D:\__GitHub\netninja_flutter_app` >    `flutter emulator`

  - Pixel_2_API_28
- `D:\__GitHub\netninja_flutter_app` >    `flutter emulator --launch Pixel_2_API_28`

  - [image]

---

[image]

- When clicked, "Nothing here" shows up.

[image]

- When clicked, the following message pops up.

  [image]

[image]

- When clicked, the following window shows up.

  [image]

  - I added a virtual device.

---

Flutter Doctor

- `D:\__GitHub\netninja_flutter_app` >    `flutter doctor -v`

  - [✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.22.2, on Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601], locale en-US)

    - [✓] Flutter version 1.22.2 at D:\src\flutter
    - [✓] Framework revision 84f3d28555 (9 days ago), 2020-10-15 16:26:19 -0700
    - [✓] Engine revision b8752bbfff
    - [✓] Dart version 2.10.2
  - [✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.)

    - [✓] Android SDK at D:\src\sdk
    - [✓] Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.2
    - [✓] ANDROID_SDK_ROOT = D:\src\sdk
    - [✓] Java binary at: D:_programs\Android\jre\bin\java
    - [✓] Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)
    - [✓] All Android licenses accepted
  - [✓] Android Studio (version 4.1.0)

    - [**!**] Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality
    - [**!**] Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality
    - [✓] Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)

=> I installed "Dart" & "Flutter" plugins. So, I don't know why the error message says that those plugins are not installed. ([This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62939342/10021131) answer says just ignore the error message. So, I did so.)
[image]

---

**QUESTION!** *How could I connect a device to this project?*

---

Comment: I have encountered a similar problem,.In my case, I had to enable developer mode in the emulator, and after I could connect it to the project.

Comment: Did you activate the developer mode on your smartphone?

Comment: Try invalidate cache & restart your Android Studio

Comment: @TamirAbutbul After reading your comment, I enabled the developer mode in the emulator. But, I still can't link my project to the emulator... :(

Comment: @ProKemikon Yes, but it's still not working... :(

Comment: Maybe it is an android studio bug, try to run your project with your emulator in visual studio code, therefor you need to install dart plugin and flutter plugin in your visual studio code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally solved the issue !!!

The following is steps I took to solve the problem:

1. Deleted Android Studio and all of related folders in the computer.

---

2-1. Create "src" folder in the C drive.

2-2. C:\src> `git clone https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git -b stable`

2-1. Type "Environment Variables" in the search box in your computer.
2-2. Under "System Variables > Path", add "`C/src/flutter/bin`".

---

3. Install "Android Studio"

3-1. Android Studio Intro Page > Configure > SDK Manager

[image]

[image]

[image]

3-2. Android Studio > Configure > Plugins > Browse Repositories (Install Dart & Flutter)
[image]

---

4. Go to "C:\src\flutter".

4-1. Run "`flutter doctor --android-licenses`"

4-2. Run "`flutter channel beta`"

4-3. Run "`flutter upgrade`"

[image]

---

5. Type "Environment Variables" in the search box in your computer.

5-2. Under "System Variables > Path", add the following:

- `C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk`
- `C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools`
- `C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools`

5-3. Under "System Variables", add the following:

- Variable Name : "`ANDROID_SDK_ROOT`"
- Variable Value : "`C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk`"

---

6. Go to "C:\src\flutter".
   6-1. Run "`flutter config --android-sdk C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk`"

---

7. Open Android Studio.

7-1. `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `Alt` + `S` > Project Settings > Project > Change "`<No SDK>`" to the latest version.
[image]

7-2. Click "AVD Manager" icon.
[image]

7-3. Click "Launch this AVD in the emulato" icon
[image]

---

8. Success!

[image]

[image]